# File.Create seems to lock the file. How can I avoid this?

Tags: c#, file

I have 2 threads that communicate by sending files to each other. When Thread #1 does a

```
// Thread #1
File.Create(@"C:\somedir\response.done");
```

Then Thread #2 is supposed to delete it.

```
// Thread #2
while (!File.Exists(@"C:\somedir\response.done"))
    Thread.Sleep(100);


while (File.Exists(@"C:\somedir\response.done"))
    {
        try {
               File.Delete(@"C:\somedir\response.done");
            }
        catch { Thread.Sleep(1000); };

    }
```

However, the file seems to be locked. There is generated a response.done file in the directory, but it is never deleted. When I try to manually remove it, then

"The action cannot be completed because the file is open in MyProgram. Close the file and try again."

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`File.Create` returns a `FileStream`. So... close it:

```
using(File.Create(path)) {
    // add contents here if needed
}
```

The `using` ensures it is `Dispose()`d, hence closed. Note: it is also possible that some AV systems will interfere with file access, but that is usually not a huge problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close `FileStream` created by `File.Create(@"C:\somedir\response.done");`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.Close()`

So your code would become

```
// Thread #1
File.Create(@"C:\somedir\response.done").Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
// Thread #1
using (FileStream FS = File.Create(@"C:\somedir\response.done") ) {};
```